# Return empty body with no content type header in java spark

Tags: spark-java

I'm creating a micro service using java spark but I'm unable to return an empty body using the framework. While i can return an empty string as body, I cannot remove the content-type header. Setting the header to null will return 404 and setting it to an empty string is lying. There is no content type as there is no body.

It feels like returning empty bodies is a fight against the framework. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        put("/hello", (request, response) -> {
            response.status(204);
            //I would like to return no body in my 204 case. That also means no content-type header. Possible with spark?
            return "";
        });
    }
}
```

Using spark 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

With `response.header("content-type", "");` you can achieve an *empty* header. It's not exactly the same as a non-existing header, but it's something...